# Different proxy servers to diferent networks

Tags: networking, network-manager, proxy

I'm looking to a alternative to configure a different proxy each time that I connect to a different network.

By example:

- Network 1 (cable) - Servers - proxy 192.168.0.1:3128
- Network 2 (wireless) - Lan - proxy 192.168.1.1:3128
- Network 3 (wireless) - Client 1 - proxy 192.168.2.1:3128
- Network 4 (wireless) - Client 2 - proxy 192.168.3.1:3128

When I connect to 'Network 1', I need to change proxy configs on network manager to 192.168.0.1:3128. When I connect to 'Network 4', I need to change proxy configs on network manager to 192.168.3.1:3128 and so on.

Is there any way to set which proxy need to be used when a connection is made only one time and not each time that I connect to a different network?

IOS has a similiar way that what I mean and can be found sample here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrNbM0lgwKY

Comment: Ops! I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: There's no simple method using the GUI that I know of, but some solutions: http://askubuntu.com/q/3554/158442

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this in a GUI, I believe. However you can try to use a so called PAC (Proxy Auto Configuration) script. This works for programs that obey the proxy settings in Ubuntu or for programs that can be set independently to a proxy like Firefox. However you need to do a bit Javascript programming. Basically you can make the script to figure out to which network you're connected and let it select the appropriate proxy. A good site with useful information is [here](http://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/).

Comment: I've already thinked about this. But I have some clients that have the same network that another one and proxy server is different. :( 

Thank you!